# Does the new LootAnime-Crunchyroll partnership mean that Loot Crate subscribers will get Crunchyroll memberships?

Tags: merchandise, crunchyroll

According to a Crunchyroll [Press Release](http://www.crunchyroll.com/anime-press-release/2016/02/19/combining-two-fan-favorite-brands-loot-anime-partners-with-crunchyroll), Loot Crate and Crunchyroll are partnering to provide a better anime themed loot crate. This service will be the replacement for the current Loot Crate anime crate and will feature current products from shows that are streaming on Crunchyroll.

From the Press Release (emphasis my own):

> Existing Loot Anime subscribers will see no change in price or frequency, but they can now look forward to even better content, **exclusive access to Crunchyroll content and more**. With packages starting at $22.95 per month, Loot Anime’s subscription price will remain the same. Every crate is valued at over $60, making this the most cost effective way for fans to enjoy a diverse mix of premium anime products.

Does this partnership mean that Loot Crate subscribers will have access to the Crunchyroll premium streaming service?

Comment: I have all of the loot crates (except pets) and I didn't get anything of such. Probably just means a discounted subscription price

Comment: @Quill This partnership was just announced on the 19th, I don't think any crates have gone out since the partnership.